# How to retrieve an image file from local drive to Crystal Reports in which the file name starts with a parameter?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to get an image file from local drive. The file name starts with a parameter value(say a number x). So I need to get the image that starts with name 'x'.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string parameter = "te"; // Replace with your parameter

        string regexp = string.Format(@"{0}.*\.png", parameter); // Change the image format as required. eg. .png to .jpg

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\FilePath");
        foreach (var fname in di.GetFiles())
        {

            if (Regex.IsMatch(fname.Name, regexp) )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fname.Name);
                // Do your processing here with the file.
            }

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Basically I am going through the directory, enumerating over the files and matching the file names against a regular expression.

Note, I have used regular expression here, if you just want to match the start of the file name, you can also use the following:

```
if (fname.Name.StartsWith(parameter) && fname.Name.EndsWith(".png"))
```

Hope this helps.